# Zener diode in stepper motor driver with TPL7407L

Tags: driver, stepper-motor, zener

In TPL7407L's [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407l.pdf), there is a stepper motor driver schematic as below

[image]

There is a zener diode denoted as "optional". However the 'COM' pin is connected to 'VSUP' directly. The 'optional' means I can remove (not short!) it, right? Then what's the purpose of the zener?

Comment: flyback ? to control inductive kick ?

Comment: If we remove it, it still can supply a path for the inductive kick back, right? (It is similar to ULN2803, with a free-wheel diode integrated.)

Comment: The zener could be used to allow the magnetic feild to collapse faster by clamping it. A huge chuck of that energy gets dropped across the zener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 9.2.2.1 Design Requirements - [...] Whenever a Zener diode is used between Vcom and the motor supply, the Vcom pin will slew from the coil supply to a voltage that is the sum of the Zener voltage and the coil supply when there is a flyback event. Depending on the coil inductance & resistance, this can be very rapid. Whenever the COM pin may experience a slew rate greater than 0.5 V/ μ s a capacitor must be added to limit the slew to < 0.5 V/ μ s. See Power Supply Recommendations for further explanation.

So in this particular case you should either:

1. Add a zener diode from motor supply to V(COM) and forget the V(SUP) at the V(COM) node.
2. Short both nodes V(COM) to motor supply.

The advantage for 1. is that the energy stored in the motor coils is being broken down more quickly and the stepper response will be 'snappier'. Notice that the motor supply increased with the zener voltage must not exceed 42V (absolute maximum, so you want to be well below that).

Comment: Yes, IMO, the schematic is not right, at least not clear enough. There shouldn't two nodes labeled 'VSUP', because they short the zener actually, right?

Comment: Agree the circuit is not clear, took me a moment to figure that out too, but the text in the datasheet was helpful.